# Prove that the sum of digits of n, when n is written in base 2, is equal to the sum of digits of 2n

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I'm trying to prove that $${2n \choose n}\text{is even }\land \text{ } 4\nmid  {2n \choose n}\Rightarrow n=2^k$$

So to prove this I need to prove the following statement:

Let $n=n_0 + n_12^1...+n_r2^r$. We define $s_2(n)$ as $$\sum_{i=0}^r n_i$$

Prove that $s_2(n)=s_2(2n)$

I know that this is true because I can write down any number as a combination of 1s and 0s and if I do n+n I'll get the same amount of 1's. I want to write it down as a general case

Comment: How you you multiply a number, written in base two, by two?

Comment: I'll add it to itself

Comment: Sounds a bit too effortful for me....

Comment: look at it this way how do you multiply by ten in base 10. what's the simplest way ?

Comment: So far what I can tell is that s2(n) is the amount of carry overs I get when adding n to itself. But I'd need to prove this for all cases as well.

Comment: Ok so I just realized that multiplying by 2 is just adding a 0 at the end. Wow that was a dumb question

Comment: still not sure how that helps you actually prove what you wanted to after that.

Comment: 2n = 0 + (n_0)*2^1 + (n_1)*2^2... +(n_r)*2^(r+1). So the sum of all digits stays the same

Comment: yeah I mean't the not dividing by 4 implication.

Comment: Ok so I wrote my question inappropiately. I need this to prove the implication going from left to right. Sorry if I wasted your time

Comment: still don't see it I see that it implies $\binom {2n} {2}$ is 2 mod 4 but that's about it for me.

Comment: If you're interested in the backwards implication, using Kummer's theorem I can say that Valuation_2 for that binomial coefficient must be exactly 1, so 2 will divide that coefficient but 4 won't

Comment: I can post the backwards implication as an answer if you're still interested

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66735/discussion-between-roddy-macphee-and-francisco-jose-letterio).